# Shared variables in Node.js

Tags: node.js

Title may seem a little misleading so let me elaborate on this. I need to set the value of a variable (within current context) and share it among other apps which needs to use this variable.

Let's say there is a counter module `counter.js`:

```
var Counter = module.exports = {
    count: 0,
    add: function() {
        Counter.count += 1;
    }
}
```

I use it in my `counter-app.js` like this:

```
var counter = require("./counter");
setInterval(function() {
    counter.add();
    console.log(counter.count);
}, 1000);
```

It starts to set and display numbers sequentially which is good so far.

While above app is running, I make another app named `counter-var.js` which contains:

```
var counter = require("./counter");
console.log(counter.count);
```

I need `counter-var.js` to print out current `Counter.count` variable value which is set by first app. Is there any way to achieve this sharing without using databases (redis, e.g.)?

Comment: What do you mean by `another app`? Another application that you start with `node counter-var.js`?

Comment: @AndreyPopov Possibly yes.

Comment: @revo There is no shared memory between node processes, so no, not without external tools.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha That was a straight bitter answer.

Comment: As a DB or an external service to do that

Comment: More on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826349/how-to-keep-variables-that-share-all-node-processes-in-node-cluster

Comment: you can use Inter-process communication for that, for example look at library https://www.npmjs.com/package/flic

Comment: ... or  you can use sockets (http://socket.io/)

Comment: You can access path variables in your node code. So if your applications are running on same server then you can access path variables.

But if you are using applications from different servers you can use node-ipc https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc.

Comment: The really true answer is that you should **not** mix and share variables between different processes. It's designed to be this way and I see no other reason doing it. Either create master-slave (worker) configuration and add communication between them, or just drop it.

Comment: @SandipNirmal What do you mean by *path variables*?

Comment: By path variables i mean system variables.